# scala: type mismatch error - found T, required String

Tags: scala, types

I'm learning scala, and this question may be stupid, but... why?

For example, this is ok:

```
def matchList(ls: List[Int]): List[Int] = ls match {
  case 1 :: rest => rest
  case a :: b :: rest => (a + b) :: rest
  case _ => ls
}

matchList: (ls: List[Int])List[Int]
```

But function with type parameter does not compile:

```
def matchList[T](ls: List[T]): List[T] = ls match {
  case 1 :: rest => rest
  case a :: b :: rest => (a + b) :: rest
  case _ => ls
}

<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
found   : T
required: String
   case a :: b :: rest => (a + b) :: rest
```

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any type `T` the operation `T + T` doesn't make any sense. (Do all types support `+`? No. Think of adding two dogs or two employees.)

In your case, the string concatenation operator is getting invoked (added via `any2stringadd` pimp), whose return type is (obviously) `String`. Hence the error message.

What you need is a **way to specify that type `T` must support an operation where you *combine* two values of type `T` to yield a new value of type `T`.** [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/)'s `Semigroup` fits the bill perfectly.

The following works:

```
def matchList[T : Semigroup](ls: List[T]): List[T] = ls match {
  case 1 :: rest => rest
  case a :: b :: rest => (a |+| b) :: rest // |+| is a generic 'combining' operator
  case _ => ls
}
```

Comment: Does he necessarily want the operation to be associative ?

Comment: He hasn't specified that. And I can't think of a case where associativity would hurt his problem.

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't : `matchList`combines at most two elements, so associativity is irrelevant. 'twas just a reminder Semigroup has a wee bigger spec than just an operation of type `T -> T -> T`. :)

Comment: I finally understood what the heck is that Semigroup! :)

Comment: it is an overhead to use a library(Scalaz) for using `+` between generics

Comment: @techkuz, you can roll your own `Semigroup` but most projects I work on have Cats/Scalaz already on path.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem lies in `(a + b)`, the only universal usage of the `+` operator is string concatenation, so `a` and `b` must both be Strings (or automatically convertible to Strings) in order for that to be valid. Your parameterized type `T` isn't known to be a String, so it fails to compile.

Comment: @confused-demon: there is an `any2string` implicit in Scala which induces a conversion in this case. There is no need for an implicit conversion in the specific `Int` case.

Comment: @confused-demon the trouble here is that Scala has no way of knowing that `T` is going to be an `Int`, so it can't work from that.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't gone so deep yet. Does `any2string implicit` mean `if type is unknown in this case it is converted to string`? And, to be complete, how that type parametrized function could be implemented to work with Int, Double and String, for example?

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, your `a`, `b` variables of declared type `T` are not convertible to `String`, which is the required argument type of `+`, inferred from your program (i.e. the *view* applied to the type of arguments of `+`in the absence of any other information).

In the first example, inference can guess the right `+` function to apply, considering it takes as arguments the type of elements of the list, and that thankfully, you have mentioned in the type declaration that the type of those elements is `Int`. Try typing

```
"1"+2

1 + 2
```

... in an REPL and see what Scala tries to do. Then read about [views](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/130).

Now, I surmise that by using that type parameter `T` above, you are trying to write a function that works with **any** numerical type, aren't you ? In that case, you can work with the `Numeric` trait. I'll let you read up on [implicits](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/114) before suggesting the following:

```
def matchList[T](ls: List[T])(implicit n:Numeric[T]): List[T] = {
  import n.mkNumericOps
  ls match {
    case 1 :: rest => rest
    case a :: b :: rest => (a + b) :: rest
    case _ => ls
}}
```

You get:

```
matchList(List(1,2,3))
res2: List[Int] = List(2, 3)
matchList(List(2,3,4))
res4: List[Int] = List(5, 4)
matchList(List(2.0,3.0,4.0))
res5: List[Double] = List(5.0, 4.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any import:

```
def matchList[T](ls: List[T])(implicit wrapper:Numeric[T]): List[T] = ls match {
  case 1 :: rest => rest
  case a :: b :: rest => wrapper.plus(a, b) :: rest
  case _ => ls
}
```